# How do force BigDecimal from rounding in JUnit assertEquals?

Tags: java, junit, bigdecimal

Everytime I run my assertEquals, my expected BigDecimal is being rounded which causes it to fail. How do I make sure it doesn't round or is there another way?

```
@Test
public void test() {
    BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(1000);
    BigDecimal interestRate = BigDecimal.valueOf(10);
    BigDecimal years = BigDecimal.valueOf(10);
    InterestCalculator ic = new InterestCalculate(amount, interestRate, years);
    BigDecimal expected = BigDecimal.valueOf(1321.507369947139705200000);
    assertEquals(expected, ic.getMonthlyPaymentAmount());
}
```

Comment: Don't think it's an exact duplicate, the other question had calls to .doubleValue() all over the place.

Answer (score 19):

Put it in quotation marks and use the `BigDecimal` constructor.

```
BigDecimal expected = new BigDecimal("1321.507369947139705200000");
```

If you don't do this, the number gets converted to a `double` first, and then to a `BigDecimal`, because `1321.507369947139705200000` is a `double` literal.  That's really not what you want.

Comment: ah duh, Thanks david!